# TeXworks spell checking error

Tags: languages, texworks, spelling

I have some problems with spell checking in TeXworks:

1. I can choose the languages under Edit/Spelling or Edit/Preferences, but then everything (except LaTeX commands) is marked as an error
2. If I choose "None" under Edit/Spelling then TeXworks exits

I have found some similar questions here, but none of them solved my problem.

Edit:
I use Windows 10.

Comment: Do you know that the speller engine is not part of TeXworks? You must  have also  `hunspell` and the dictionary files. In Debian-like Linux systems, this could be some like `sudo  apt-get install hunspell  hunspell-dictionary-es hunspell-dictionary-fr hunspell-dictionary-<whatever> ...`

Comment: @Fran I have language dictionaries, English, German, etc. were installed by default. I recently reinstalled MiKTeX, before that spell checking worked well.

Comment: @Fran I have the language dictionaries in the .../MiKTeX 2.9/hunspell/dicts folder. Do I have to install anything else?

Comment: I guess that install Hunspell (the executable program, not only the dictionaries)  and add the path to this program in Edit > Preferences.